# Call a firebase storage list but only stop loading when all files have been listed

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, vuejs3, firebase-storage

Below is the code I have for my firebase storage composable I then call and use in all my other vue.js views:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { projectStorage } from "../firebase/config";

//all the files at the root in one array
const mixed = ref([]);
const loading = ref(true);

//function to list all the contents of a folder
const  getClientFiles = async (folder) => {
  const listRef = projectStorage.ref(folder);

  listRef
    .list()
    .then((res) => {
      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
        // All the prefixes under listRef.
        mixed.value.push({
          name: folderRef.name,
          type: "Folder",
          size: "--",
          lastUpdated: "--",
          url: "--",
        });
      });
      if (res.items.length > 0) {
        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
          let one = {
            name: itemRef.name,
            type: "Folder",
            size: "--",
            lastUpdated: "--",
            url: "--",
          };

          // All the items under listRef.
          itemRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            // console.log ("download url: " + url)
            one.url = url;
          });

          itemRef.getMetadata().then((metadata) => {
            // Metadata now contains the metadata for each itemRef
            (one.type = metadata.contentType),
              (one.size = metadata.size),
              (one.lastUpdated = metadata.timeCreated);
          });
          mixed.value.push(one);
        });
        console.log(mixed.value)
        loading.value = false
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      console.log(error);
    }).finally(() => {
if (mixed.value.length > 0){
    loading.value = false
}
    })
}

export { getClientFiles, loading, Files, Items, mixed, meta, links };
```

The issue I am having is that the code lists all the elements in the mixed array as references at first. And can only be updated after I press a button that basically updates something in the DOM.

Is there a way to cause loading to still be true until all the folders and files are ready and pushed into the mixed array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to wait for the single `list` call and then all `getDownloadURL` calls to complete.

It's easiest to do that by using `await` rather than `then`, and [using `for...of` rather than `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). With those two changes, the code would look something like this:

```
const getClientFiles = async (folder) => {
  const listRef = projectStorage.ref(folder);

  const res = await listRef.list();
  for (const folderRef of res.prefixes) {
    mixed.value.push({
      name: folderRef.name,
      type: "Folder",
      size: "--",
      lastUpdated: "--",
      url: "--",
    });
  }

  if (res.items.length > 0) {
    for (const itemRef of res.items) {
      let one = {
        name: itemRef.name,
        type: "Folder",
        size: "--",
        lastUpdated: "--",
        url: "--",
      };

      one.url = await itemRef.getDownloadURL()
      const metadata = await itemRef.getMetadata()
      one.type = metadata.contentType);
      one.size = metadata.size;
      one.lastUpdated = metadata.timeCreated;

      mixed.value.push(one);
    });
  }
  loading.value = false
}
```

There may be some syntax and minor other errors in here, so please focus on the big changes which are the use of `await` and `for...of` loops.